# How to make bpchem/auto-pst-pdf work with hyperref?

Tags: errors, hyperref, chemistry, auto-pst-pdf, bpchem

I'm using the bpchem package along with the auto-pst-pdf package to do molecules numbering in .eps chemdraw files (as well as in the bulk document) and I noticed that it does not work  when the package hyperref is also used in the document.  I get a "MikTeX Ghostscript error 9.05, unrecoverable error", the document compiles but will not print the numbers on the .eps figures.

Here are the packages I use for chemistry, in case I misidentified the source of the error:

```
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage[runs=2,crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf} %To make LaTeX able to convert .eps to .pdf
\usepackage{bpchem} %To make the numerotation of the chemical compounds
\usepackage[tracking=bpchem]{chemstyle} % idem
\renewcommand*{\schemerefformat}{\scriptsize}%Size of the numbers of the molecules in the schemes
\usepackage{xspace} 
\renewcommand{\theBPCnoa}{\textbf{\arabic{BPCno}\alph{BPCnoa}\kern-0.5ex\xspace}} %To avoid having a space after the "4a" notation, for example.
```

Anybody know why, or which package I could use to get the same result as hyperref?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered switching to [`chemnum`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/chemnum/chemnum_en.pdf) package? It still doesn't support hyperlinking to compounds, but I think it works better and faster then `chemstyle`...